# Can we use logon trigger to update login activity of a customer in a website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have searched and found that "logon" trigger is used to track user login activity in SQL server.

Search links:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/27/sql-server-interesting-observation-of-logon-trigger-on-all-servers/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb326598%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Can we use logon trigger to update login activity of a customer in a website developed in ASP.NET MVC?

Is there any use of logon trigger apart from tracking user activity in SQL server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Membership or a custom login store and membership api?

Comment: I am using custom one